# Sending arguments to gesture recognizer initialization selector?

Tags: objective-c, ios, methods, selector, uitapgesturerecognizer

In my program, I have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` which I have initialized with `initWithTarget: action:`. I have passed in a selector to call a method by the name of `PlanetTapped: (UIImageView *)aPlanet`. This calls the method fine, however I would like to know how to pass arguments into `action:` like you would with `performSelector: withObject`. Is this popssible? It would make sense to allow you to send arguments to the `UIGestureRecognizer`'s selector. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The correct signature for the method to call would be:

```
-(void) PlanetTapped: (UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
```

then you could access the view that received the gesture by calling:

```
-(void) PlanetTapped: (UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {

    UIImageView* aPlanet = gestureRecognizer.view;
    ...
}
```

Indeed, this is what [UIGestureRecognizer reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states:

> A gesture recognizer has one or more target-action pairs associated with it. If there are multiple target-action pairs, they are discrete, and not cumulative. Recognition of a gesture results in the dispatch of an action message to a target for each of those pairs. The action methods invoked must conform to one of the following signatures:
>
> - (void)handleGesture;
> - (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;

Comment: Ahh, of course. I should've thought of that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressOnPhotos:)];
[yourView addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];
}



- (IBAction)handleLongPressOnPhotos:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender{
// use "sender.view" to get the "yourView" you have long pressed
}
```

hope these would help you.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3.0, the function signature is as follows (substitute another gesture recognizer class as appropriate in these examples):

```
func myButtonLongTouch(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
```

You reference this function when setting up your Gesture Recognizers as follows:

```
longTouchGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(myButtonLongTouch(_:)))
```

Then, to access the view (in my case, a button) that was pressed, use the code:

```
if let button = sender.view as? UIButton {
    // Your code here
}
```

Finally, don't forget that this function is called multiple times (typically when the gesture begins and when it ends), so you'll want to check the state, which you can do as follows:

```
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended) {
    // Your code here
}
```